# 行選択した後に、列選択をして、その行列が合わさったところに数字（value）を挿入するやり方がわからない

Tags: python, python3, pandas

filei0 一枚目
[image: インポートされるファイルです。]
file01　二枚目（下記二枚とも同じファイルの内容です）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
filei0 = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', index_col=0)
file01 = pd.read_csv('faostat_sample.csv')

for i in range(len(filei0)):

    irow = filei0.iloc[i]
    icountry = irow["Area"]
    iitem = irow["Item"]
    ielement = irow["Element"]
    ivalue = irow["Value"]
    iyear = irow["Year Code"]
    if [(file01["countries"] == icountry) & (file01["item"] == iitem) & (file01["element"] == ielement)]:
    [iyear] = ivalue
    file01.loc[i]
file01.to_csv('sample_full.csv')
```

国名,element,item,yearが同じものをfileo1(二枚目の画像）の2001～の年に一枚目の画像のvalue値を挿入したいのですが、コードをどうつけ足せばいいかわかりません

行を選択したあとの書き出し方？がわからないのですがどのようなコードを書けばよいのでしょうか

Comment: 私には2枚表示されているように見えます。ただコード中の`fileo1`は`file01`（`o`(ｵｰ)と`0`(ｾﾞﾛ)）と混同しているように思いますので見直していただきたく思います。

Comment: @カントリーくん 貼られた画像は3枚ありますが、実際に表示されているのは2枚になっています。説明が食い違っているといけないので、念のため見直してみて必要なら質問文を修正してみてください。後からでも [編集] できます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。不備があり申し訳ございません。表示されている画像の編集をおこないました。再度ご確認してコメントいただけましたら嬉しいです。

Comment: pivot_table を使うと1文程度で簡単にできそうですが。[都市と年度の表を作成(pivot_table)](https://qiita.com/grachro/items/8da18678eaae0caefcb8#%E9%83%BD%E5%B8%82%E3%81%A8%E5%B9%B4%E5%BA%A6%E3%81%AE%E8%A1%A8%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90pivot_table)

Comment: あああああああああ3行できました
有難うございます！！！